# Cordova onResume but not on file input

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm using cordova and the onResume function. The reason why is that I want to reload the app when it comes from the background. That is working fine! Now the problem is when a user select a file with an input field. Apparently that, selecting a file, is also moving the app in the background. So when the file is selected, the app gets reloaded and the selected file is gone.

The resume function:

```
 <script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false); 
  }, false);
  function onResume() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload(false); 
    }, 0);
  }
</script>
```

Is it possible to disable the resume function on a file select?

Comment: Yes, simply use flag, or a boolean variable, something like `isFileSelected = true`, and if `isFileSelected === true` then you do not reload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain how to set the flag when a user is selecting a  file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a flag, or a boolean variable that detects when a file input is being used.

```
<input type="file" id="myFileSelection">
```

jQuery

```
$('#myFileSelection').click(function() {
  window.isFileSelected = true;
});
```

Then just modify your onResume logic to include the flag.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false); 
}, false);
function onResume() {
  // if isFileSelected is true stop the code here with 'return false', will not execute the setTimeout
  if (window.isFileSelected) {
    // set this to false to reset the variable
    window.isFileSelected = false;
    return false;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(false); 
  }, 0);
}
```

I have not tested this code, but this is generally how you can go about this.